# NumberFormatException while reading CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file and then compare the numbers with ui data. There are some fields in the CSV file, where there is no number entry, in other words, there is no value for some fields. I tried to convert all the entries in the CSV file to `Double` format:

```
public String convertToCurrency(String cost){
    if(cost!=null){
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return nf.format(Double.valueOf(cost));
    }
    else 
        return cost="";
}
```

But I am getting the [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html). How do I avoid it?

Comment: First, are you using C#? Cannot you use String.IsNullorEmpty instead of cost!= null? Are you getting a valid string? Do you knows due to locale you can get "1,000.99" or "1.000,99" as valid inputs?

Comment: Im using Java. I guess I can use cost.isEmpty. I am getting an empty string error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if input *String* `cost` [`isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29).

Replace expression inside `if` statement

```
cost!=null
```

with

```
cost!=null && !cost.isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the only values are:

1. A valid currency,
2. `null`,
3. The empty string.

Then you could change your code to

```
public String convertToCurrency(String cost){
    if(cost!=null && cost.length != 0){
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return nf.format(Double.valueOf(cost));
    } else { 
        return "";
    }
}
```

However, you might be better to do both of those *and* include an exception handler for unknown (exceptional) values. If you don't do this then there is always a chance that your calling function will have to deal with a NumberFormatException from your code.

Here's the code with an additional exception handler:

```
public String convertToCurrency(String cost){
    if(cost!=null && cost.length != 0){
        try {
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            return nf.format(Double.valueOf(cost));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Some appropriate logging
            return "";
        }
    } else { 
        return "";
    }
}
```